# How do I get the old `du` behaviour back?

Tags: disk-usage

Trying to move stuff around on my server (Ubuntu 12.04) I wanted to know the size of each of the subdirectories of the current directory and the total for the current directory using `du`:

```
$ du -sm * .
34      A
23      B 
1       .
```

I read this as that the total of the sizes of the subdirectories (the sum of the values on the first two lines) is greater than that of the current directory together with its subdirectories (the last line). On a server running Ubuntu 8.04 this still works as when I first used the `-sm` option 30 years ago:

```
$ cd /var/spool
$ du -sm * .
1      cron
1      cups
0      mail
2      postfix
3      .
```

The cause for this difference is that on the Ubuntu 12.04 machine I have `coreutils` version  8.13 and on Ubuntu 8.04 there is `coreutils` 6.10. There has been some optimization, probably related to [this](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/src/du.c?id=efe53cc72b599979ea292754ecfe8abf7c839d22), that doesn't count/display directories twice even if specified on the commandline: on the newer version `du -sm . .` only gives a one-line answer on the old version an answer with two identical lines.

On the 12.04 machine I could do `du -sm * ; du -sm .` but doing that for the directories that I am actually interested in is not an option as there are 28 direct children with over a terabyte of data in several million files. Walking once over this directory tree ones takes hours and since the directory information seems to big for the OS to cache, immediately running a second `du` takes the same amount of time (i.e. I do not have the typical effect that when you run `du -s` twice on a larger subtree the second time is much faster).

I know I can `tee` the result into a program and add the values in the first column, but it would be nice if there is a way to get the old `du` behaviour back.

Is there a commandline option that I missed for coreutils `du` or an alternative `du` that I can install?

(I am also under the impression that `du` has become slower, but that might be because the amount of data I store and handle has grown over the years. And the 12.04 system is running Btrfs and that has slowed down many things, hence the moving around).

Comment: Have you tried `ncdu`? It shows all directories with it's sizes and you can browse through it.

Comment: Have you considered `du -c`?

Comment: `du --max-depth=1`

Comment: @jw013 `du -c` should do what I want. I seems I have been doing `du -sm * .` forever (but not recently) and never noticed that option.

Answer (score 3):

```
du dir1 dir2
```

Reports the disk usage of all of `dir1`, `dir2` and their content recursively. Files are only counted once, otherwise that would give a wrong answer on the disk usage.

You can use:

```
du -c dir1 dir2
```

If you also want the total disk usage of both.

So:

```
du -sc -- *
```

would give you a summary of the disk usage of the non-hidden files and dirs in the current directory and their cumulative size.

With GNU `du`, you can also do:

```
du -ad1
```

or

```
du -a --max-depth=1
```

To only report disk usage at up to one level down (so `.` and the subdirs), here using `-a` to report non-dirs in the current directory like your `du *` would.

You can force GNU `du` to count files several times with the `-l` option:

```
du -ls -- * .
```

Not efficient and unlikely to be what you really want.

Answer (score 3):

The option `-c` produces a total, which means that, **in your use case**, the command `du -smc *` gives almost (`.` is replaced by `total`) the same output than `du -sm * .` with previous versions of `du`:

```
$ du -smc *
34  A
23  B
57  total
```

Even if you have different use cases than the one given in your question, I think the `-c` option may anyway help you get a result close to the one you use to have.